# Forwarded email replay with phpmailer

Tags: email, gmail, phpmailer, using, forward

I have question script for running forward my own email (do not have autoforward facility) to my Gmail. I want to do it using phpmailer.
So I can make cronjobs for running php script everyday (running get email and forwading to my Gmail).

How can I go forward with this?

Answer (score 0):

PHPmailer alone will not be able to help you with forwarding as it is only a transfer class, for outgoing emails. You will need to set up a mail server (like Postfix) with an email handler (like Dovecot) if you are in Linux to receive incoming emails. PHPmailer can be used for the forwarding process but there are other solutions.

I recommend you look into a service like [mailgun.com](http://mailgun.com) instead. They have a routing feature for forwarding incoming emails that is very easy to set up (if you have dns access to your current email domain). You can send 10k emails for free each month with the service.